# How to configure Websphere 7 to always include "X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff" in response headers?

Tags: security, websphere

I'm working on application scan using OWASP and got this report. what i think is that, to configure WAS to include the header in all response headers it there's a way. thanks in advance for all your answers.

Vulnerability: 
The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'. This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type. 
Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.

Suggested Solution: 
Set the "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" header for resources (javascript, css, etc.) that are directly served by the web server. This can be done through server configuration so this might involve documentation updates.

Affected URLs / resources: 
https://css-acme-tst.usmt0520.lpc.lawson.com/sso/domain.js 
https://css-acme-tst.usmt0520.lpc.lawson.com/sso/login.css

---

What i did so far.

what i did is this. i place the tags right after commented out property modules/mod_headers.so and restart my appserver but still the same response header.

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

 <Directory mod_headers.c>
      Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
 </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it into IfModule instead or into VirtualHost.

I have tried this one and it works fine:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi **Magic Wand** Just wondering if js files are also affeted on this configuration change?

Comment: Yup, that's right, all static files are also affected (CSS, JS, images). According to html5 boilerplate .htaccess config on https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess, it is advisable to put it also on static content.